# nutch index-metadata not indexing

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, plugins, meta-tags, nutch

I'm trying to index some metada from meta tags witch Nutch. I've follewed the step by step tutorial [Nutch - Parse Metatags](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexMetatags) but nothing is indexed.

I've configured the plugin like the step by step tutorial. When I run the crawl process I can read that 15 docuements are indexed in the log but when I look in elastic I can't see them. The index is created but it has 0 documents. There are no errors in the log.

> Indexer: number of documents indexed, deleted, or skipped:
>
> Indexer:     15  indexed (add/update)
>
> Indexer: finished at 2017-12-20 12:42:58, elapsed: 00:00:04

If I remove the index-metadata plugin and rerun the crawling process the documents are writed in Elastic but they don't have the metatags.

How can I crawl the metatags with Nutch and Elastic? Why anything is indexed when I activate that plugin?

I'm using apache-nutch-1.13 with elastic.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Elastic was throwing errors due to the field names. The names that the plugin was creating were "metadata.*". Elastic doesn't accept points in the field names. To solve it you have to configure the index-metadata without the prefix "metedata.". This prefix is only for Solr.

```
<property>
  <name>metatags.names</name>
  <value>description,keywords</value>
  <description>...</description>
</property>
...
<property>
  <name>index.parse.md</name>
  <value>description,keywords</value>
  <description>...</description>
</property>
```